# How to pick a Lyapunov function and estimate PID gains?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am currently trying to estimate the range of PID gains by developing a Lyapunov function for a nonlinear 6-Dof quadrotor system. The system is of the following form:

$$M(q)\ddot{q}+C(q,\dot q)\dot q+g(q)=\tau$$
$$\tau=K_p\tilde{q}+K_v\dot{\tilde{q}}+K_i\int_0^t\tilde{q}(s)ds,$$

where M is the Inertia Matrix, C is the Coriolis term, g is the Gravity term, tau is the PID control input and q is the state vector.

The problem is, I can't find any generalized approach for developing said functions and estimating the gains. Can someone provide insight or a link to any reference material?

Comment: Your question lacks context and details. Please provide more details about the system and the control problem.

Comment: What models are you using for the mechanical systems, linear?

Comment: Hello. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Please transcribe to MathJax and remove the images.

Comment: Have you tried to linearize the system around the desired steady-state and use this linearization to find suitable gains for the controllers?

Comment: What you are trying to do has been extensively studied in the literature. Many papers and books have been devoted to this topic. I am sure there are a lot of lecture notes available for free as well. Check, for instance, the book "Check the book "PID Trajectory Tracking Control for Mechanical Systems" by Youngjin Choi and Wan Kyun Chung.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question lacks the control objective, e.g., regulation to an equilibrium point.
I'll assume that your control objective is to regulate the state of the given system to the origin (which is an equilibrium point) by a feedback controller.

Before that, it is convenient to consider the following form,
$$
\dot{x} = f(x, u),
$$
where $x = [x_1, x_2]^{\intercal} = [q, \dot{q}]^{\intercal}$ and $u = \tau$. More specifically, assuming that $M$ is invertible for any $x$,
$$
\dot{x}_1 = x_2,
$$
$$
\dot{x}_2 = M(x_1)^{-1}(-C(x_1, x_2)x_2 - g(x_1) + u).
$$

A standard way to design a control law would be nonlinear dynamic inversion (NDI): setting $u = C(x_1, x_2)x_2 + g(x_1) + M(x_1) \nu$ implies
$$
\dot{x}_2 = \nu,
$$
where $\nu$ is the virtual control input.
Now, you can design some asymptotically stable feedback controllers for the obtained linear system.

IMO, the stability analysis of PID controllers is mostly based on linear system control theory.
So you can apply the PID control method to the obtained linear systems,
but for the general mechanical system control, it is more practical.
It should be pointed out that in practice, PID control works quite well even for nonlinear system control (but mostly at the neighbourhood of the origin).

P.S. there are too many categories of control problems; regulation to the origin, finite-time convergence, optimal control, tracking control, model-based or model-free control design...
There would be some desired design patterns or specific control methods for each control objective, that's why you have to clarify your interest.

Comment: Your system has one dimension more than necessary. $\dot{x}_3$ is equal to $\dddot{q}$ not $\ddot{q}$. Also, the NDI is not robust at all. The OP asks explicitly about tuning a PID controller.

Comment: @KBS Sorry, I was confused. I'll fix it. I agree that NDI is not robust. It's just a very simple example, and I think the question lacks details of the control objective.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You have given a very detailed answer. The problem at hand is of trajectory tracking, and the problem has been defined in a manner such that I have to use the control structure of PID and model the lyapunov function in such a manner as to estimate a set of values for the gains.

Answer (score 0):

From the symbols $\tilde{q}$ and $\dot{\tilde{q}}$, it seems that they are errors, and therefore, this looks like some kind of a tracking control problem to track a reference trajectory $q_{\text{ref}}$, i.e., $\tilde{q} = q_{\text{ref}} - q$. After all, the model describes the motion of a quadrotor aerial vehicle in 6 degrees of freedom.

However, I'm unsure if there is the Lyapunov stability approach to estimate or to compute the PID control gains. If the control input structure is already fixed at
$$
\tau_{\text{pid}} = K_{p} \tilde{q} + K_{i} \int \tilde{q}(s)\;ds + K_{d} \dot{\tilde{q}}
$$
where the control gains $K_{p}$, $K_{i}$, $K_{d}$ are some constant values to be designed, then I suggest to use the **Gain-scheduling control design** approach that allows to control the quadrotor system with dynamics changing from one operating condition to another, throughout the flying trajectory.

Miscellaneous works on designing the gain-scheduled controller are available in the literature or online. You can also find examples in these links and learn how to adopt the design process into your quadrotor:

https://www.mathworks.com/videos/gain-scheduling-of-pid-controllers-68883.html
https://www.mathworks.com/videos/automatic-tuning-of-gain-scheduled-controllers-86776.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/tuning-of-gain-scheduled-three-loop-autopilot.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/gain-scheduled-control-of-a-chemical-reactor.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is to estimate a set of PID gains by studying the stability of the closed loop nonlinear system for trajectory tracking control of the Quadrotor.